# How to pass dynamic SQL statement to the JDBCIO connector in apache beam?

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

Apache beam provides the JDBCIO connector to connect to CloudSql postgreSQL. My job reads an event from pub/sub. The event body is as below:

```
tableName,
list<value>
```

I need to write to the table based on the table name that I get in from my message.

The JDBCIO has prepared statement which will let me parameterize the values in my insert query. But I need to generate the insert query dynamically based on the information present in the event.

```
 pipeline
   .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription())
   .apply(convertToKV())
   .apply(JdbcIO.<List<String>>>write()
      .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/mydb")
          .withUsername("username")
          .withPassword("password"))
      .withStatement("insert into Person values(?, ?)")
      .withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<KV<Integer, String>>() {
        public void setParameters(KV<Integer, String> element, PreparedStatement query)
          throws SQLException {
i=0
for each element in list
          query.setInt(i, element.get(i);
i++;

        }
      })
    );
```

I should be able to create the SQL statement dynamically based on the input event from the pcollection.
My select statement should be dynamically generated based on the list value and the table name. Please let me know whether we can do this or not.

Update:-

im trying to manually call the jdbc driver inside the parDo function but getting the below error.
No suitable driver found for jdbcURL.

Please let me know if im missing anyting:

```
@Setup
public void doAnyRequiredSetup() throws SQLException
{
    LoggingContextUtil.installContext(loggingContext);


    connection=DriverManager.getConnection(JdbcUrl,user,password);
    statement=connection.createStatement();

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("In doAnyRequiredSetup logging Context is now set and JDBC connection is .");
    }



}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext context)
{
    JsonNode element=context.element();

    try {
        String query=formatQuery(baseQuery);

        boolean result=statement.execute(query);

        if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Executed query : "+query+" and the result is "+ result);
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SQLException e) {

        ErrorMessage em = new ErrorMessage(element.toString(), "Insert Query Failed", e.getMessage());

        context.output(ValidateTagHelper.FAILURE_TAG,em);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have dynamic queries on JdbcIO based on the input elements. 
The ParDo has to reset as you like, you can rewrite your ParDo in which you would call the JDBC driver manually.

If find this other workaround, you can split the input PColleciton into multiple outputs. That will work if your use case is limited to some predefined set of queries that you can choose from based on the input. This way you split the input into multiple PCollections and then attach differently configured IOs to each.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1

Comment: Do you mean , i should initiate a jdbc connection in my setup function, construct and execute the statement inside the process element function ?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to read pubsub messages with attributes and in attributes, you can pass the table name and values in the form of Key-value pair.

```
PCollection<PubsubMessage> pubsubMessage = pipeline
      .apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription("")
```